# No breadcrumbs support for eclipse-CDT?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt, breadcrumbs

I'm so used to working with Eclipse for java related projects that I thought I'd work with Eclipse CDT for C-projects too. 'Show in Breadcrumbs' was a nifty little feature that would show what method the cursor currently is at (in Eclipse JAVA).

I don't see that option in Eclipse CDT. Is it in some way, hard to implement? The closest I could find to using the breadcrumbs feature was this :

> Go to Outline pane, open its menu (down arrowhead on the top, right
>   side) and check the box "Link With Editor". Now the method name will
>   be highlighted to coincide with the cursor location.

From(source) : [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/155322/#page_top).

Are there any other alternatives to get the Breadcrumbs feature working under Eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 4):

No. :-(

- The option `Link with Editor` is not only available in the Outline view, but also in the Project Explorer view, and others
- You can use Mylyn, which also automatically links the Project Explorer view with the file/function you edit.