# Any way in Eclilpse to see what method your cursor is in, without scrolling up to the top of the method?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I work with some very large files in Eclipse (3.5.2)

As I move the cursor around inside the file, I can lose track of which method my cursor currently in.  As such I have to scroll all the way back up to the top of the function to see it's name.

Does anyone know of a way to have this displayed in Eclipse's user interface?

Comment: Just a note for future people looking at this question:  To enable your cursor to be tracked, go to outline view, hit the little down arrow, and check "Link With Editor".  Just thought I'd add this note as I had issues finding how to get Outline to track the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Outline view open, it tracks which method your cursor's in.

Comment: And if you don't (I don't use this view to save space), you can use ctrl+o :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to turn on the "breadcrumb" across the top of the editor.  It shows the full path to where you are: project -> source folder -> package -> class -> method/field.

Edit: It seems this feature is [only available in JDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202732/no-breadcrumbs-support-for-eclipse-cdt).  Outline view seems to be your only option.